# Redirect issue: folders and files not redirected properly

Tags: .htaccess, configuration, url, redirection

I have recently set a new URL http://www.mytechnotes.biz for a blog I was maintaining on a subdomain http://technotes.tostaky.biz.

The redirection works in the following cases:

```
technotes.tostaky.biz -> www.mytechnotes.biz
www.technotes.tostaky.biz -> www.mytechnotes.biz
```

But it does not work in this case:

```
http://technotes.tostaky.biz/2012/11/introduction-to-css-concepts.html
```

Yet, the following page exists:

```
www.technotes.biz/2012/11/introduction-to-css-concepts.html
```

The content of my `.htaccess` file is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^technotes\.tostaky\.biz$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.technotes\.tostaky\.biz$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.mytechnotes\.biz\/" [R=301,L]
```

I am not a sysadmin. I am relying on CPanel configuration of my host, but I can't resolve this issue. Anyone knows how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern (thing that gets matched) in your RewriteRule, `^/?$`, explicitly only matches the root URL of the domain.  I think what you want is to match anything, and include it in the redirected URL:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mytechnotes.biz/$1 [R=301,L]
```